# dynamically menu smooth scroll to specific Id on click in angular 14

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am using angular 14, We want to scroll the menu in the one-page application by its id. and how to get the ID from another component in the ts file.

**header.component.html**

```
<li class="nav-item active " (click)="scolluser()"  *ngFor="let users of user">
```

**header.component.ts**

```
  scolluser() {
    this.scroller.scrollToAnchor("service");  // get id dynamically from another components 

  }
```

Comment: how about [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scroll-fullpage-easily-with-content?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)